# Selenium-How to check if text exists in a listbox

Tags: c#, selenium, listbox

I am trying to verify if the added text in a list box has been successfully removed or not. What is the best way to handle this type of scenario in Selenium with C#?

Given below is the code I am using currently.

```
//Verify that the subject is added and then deleted
    public static void VerifySubjectDel()
    {
        string subjectAddValue = GenerateRandomAlphaCode(200);
        productPage.subjectAddTxtBx.SendKeys(subjectAddValue);
        productPage.subjectAddBtn.Click();

        IWebElement elem = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("Subjects_ListBox"));
        SelectElement selectList = new SelectElement(elem);
        IList<IWebElement> options = selectList.Options;

        if (options.ToList().Any(tagname => tagname.Text.Contains(subjectAddValue)))
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
            selectList.SelectByText(subjectAddValue);
            productPage.subjectDelBtn.Click();
            WebDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
            bool subjectDel = WebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@id='Subjects_ListBox']//option[contains(text(),'" + subjectAddValue + "')]")).Count == 0;
            if (subjectDel)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(subjectDel);
            }
            else
                Assert.IsTrue(subjectDel, "Subject not deleted successfully");
        }
        else
            Assert.IsTrue(false, "The Subject added is not present in the Subject-ListBox");
    }
```

Comment: Try using **CollectionAssert.DoesNotContain()**

Answer (score 0):

I would call FindElements on the IWebElement you captured above and return all the elements within the list box. Then using LINQ you could do something like

```
bool success = !listBoxItems.Any(x => string.Compare(x.Text, subjectAddValue) == 0):
```